# Screen video recording android

Tags: android, record

Can anyone share app/ways to record current android screen device?
i know this app:
http://tandroidapk.blogspot.com/2011/12/screencast-video-recorder-android-app.html
but somehow i can't installed it in my HTC Hero device.

Is there any other solution?
I can't use emulator because I'm using accelerometer function
Thanks.

Comment: c++ version of screen recorder for the application developement reference. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077  visit this link for working FFMPEG c++ mp4 format screen recorder application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out :
http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/

This will get your android device screen to your laptop. Use some screen recording software for PC/Mac (e.g.: Camtasia Studio) to do screen recording and save.

Comment: I have tried it and it's not a video it's a recording screen-shots and store them into a directory. But what i really want a video if you have other solution. The fastest is only 100 frames/minute if i use that picture become video is not smooth. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few months I wrote a summary of the available root and non-root recorder apps here:

http://recordable.mobi/compare

In addition to apps there are some USB tools (e.g., Mobizen) that stream the screen across USB (limited by low USB bandwdith and can't record audio) and some devices can also transmit the screen over wifi, which can then captured on a separate device.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into platform-tools directory from cmd

Follow this command to check if your device exist

```
H:\ANDROID\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
***********        device
```

Follow this command to record screen

```
H:\ANDROID\sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
The max width/height supported by codec is 640x480
```

Press Ctrl+C to exit

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Telecine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jakewharton.telecine) by [Jake Wharton](https://jakewharton.github.io).

If you're interested in how this app works, lucky you as there is source code available at Github https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine