# Screen Video Recording FPS

Tags: android, screen, video-recording

I have searched a lot on google but unfortunately have not found any solution of screen video recording. If you have used the **[Screencast Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast&hl=en)** from google play, you can better understand my question. Can anyone help me out that how to achieve screen video recording **programmatically**.

Comment: Unless this is for an API, this does not appear to be a programming-related question. I think that this question would be a more appropriate fit for http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to do this programmatically...

Comment: Oh, alright. Which language?

Comment: Oh yeah Java. Sorry for my dumb moment. :)

Comment: Why don't you repost (and delete) this question, because nobody's seeming to answer it. Or you could set a bounty. I honestly don't know this stuff. When it comes to Android, I think it's wiser for me to stop with my two-cents. :)

Comment: Share your research how you capture video recording of the screen programmatically

Comment: C++ version of screen recorder  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077 visit this link for working FFMPEG c++ mp4 format screen recorder application.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Screencast records by reading /dev/graphics/fb0, which is slow.

Programmatically the highest performance method is to create a virtual display. Currently only works on Android 4.4. See the screenrecorder.cpp for how to do this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4_r1/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp

For Android 4.1 and above you can use the SurfaceComposerClient (both from native or Java code), although it's fairly broken on 4.3.

Unless you want to write a screen recorder yourself I wouldn't bother and just use one of the off-the-shelf recorders.

for some more detail see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697099/screen-video-recording-android/22985257#22985257).