# Record own app view or activity in android to video file

Tags: android, file, video, screen, record

I'm try to make an app that records a view into a video file. But i can't find a way to do this.

How can I record the screen of my app in `Android` to a video file(Without adb, computer or another program)?

Answer (score 0):

You can record the View hierarchy of your app to a video file, but normal apps CANNOT record the *screen* without either root or another program started via adb. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697099/screen-video-recording-android/22985257#22985257).