# Record screen in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, camera

I am making a web application where I am currently using a web camera to capture the bar-codes from the screen and then decoding them. I am trying to accomplish this without a camera. 
Instead of taking the video from a camera, is there a way to record the screen programmatically. There are open source screen recorders such as CamStudio.

**Is there anyways I can incorporate screen recording in a video format in my asp.net c# web application?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I typed `html5 screen capture` into Google and found [this](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html)

Comment: navigator.getUserMedia() enables the application to use the users hardware. I am trying to capture the screen without a camera. As in a screen recording software.

Comment: From *What's this* which is the first button the page *Example of using the navigator.getUserMedia() API extensions to do screen capturing. Note, this is true screen sharing (e.g. more than just the browser tab) and not tab content sharing.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077 visit this link for working FFMPEG c++ mp4 format screen recorder application.