# Unable to record window with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to video-record a browser window with `ffmpeg`. The browser window is a firefox window with title `OpenID Connect Server - Log In`, so I tried the following command (based on the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396784/how-to-record-a-specific-window-using-ffmpeg)):

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -i title="OpenID Connect Server - Log In" -b:v 3M  germ.flv
```

but I get an error

```
[x11grab @ 0x1fd7980] Cannot open display title=OpenID Connect Server - Log In, error 5.
title=OpenID Connect Server - Log In: Input/output error
```

Anything I am missing?

**Addition:**

1. I need a tool to be used on command line (starting and stopping recording).
2. The goal is to record selenium tests from a window. But I need to run like 50 tests, which all open and close their own firefox window. Therefore I need the command line ability.

Comment: Selecting region by title is not implemented in x11grab device.

Comment: So what can I do instead? I tried already other 'devices' but none of them were installed/available...

Comment: if you are looking to develop the application using FFMPEG in Linux platform, check here: https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp

Comment: No sorry, I want a complete command line solution. And the link you posted seems to be a GUI application without documentation. Not useable.

Comment: At best, you can set video_size and grab_x/grab_y to capture region where window is located. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-20