# Record specific window using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been trying the below code (which I found on other similiar problem on this site here: [How to record a specific window using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396784/how-to-record-a-specific-window-using-ffmpeg/30911430#30911430?newreg=3dd064f0a87040189008a4c43bbe2362) But it gives me black video and the same video is not playable by windows media player (it works on vlc but with black video..)

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="german.avi - VLC media player" -b:v 3M  germ.flv
```

Video example:
[Weird thumbnail by WMP which shows it can't play it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo1sD.png)
[Black screen as described, but it opens with black video in VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7v78.png)

I tried the other suggestions, but this one sometimes (less than 40% of the time) works.
I also noticed it doesn't show the window main title, which is a bit confusing, as it causes the mouse cursor to appear a little down where it should be.

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: @Gyan can you explain more what does that add? more about the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gyan suggested, The answer is to add -pix_fmt parameter to the command, specifically this way:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="WINDOW MAIN TITLE HERE" -b:v 3M -pix_fmt yuv420p output_FILENAME.mp4
```

This also seems to fix the wrong cursor position somehow, But still you can't see the window title bar in the video.

Comment: I still get black screen, any suggest? im using windows 10

Comment: @ManarHidayat where do you get it exactly?