# Record screen video and audio -Windows 7

Tags: audio, video, screen-capture

I've been trying for weeks to get this working and feel like I am going around in circles.
I want to create a desktop application similar to CamStudio that can record user actions on the desktop and their voice on the microphone and save it to a video file.

I've tried a number of approaches.

- FFMPEG - I cannot get a clear video, it is blurry.
- AForge.Video.FFMPEG - gets me a slightly better video but I do not know how to add sound
- Camstudio source - I looked at this but cannot get the code to compile, C++ is not my strong suit and it seems VC++ 2010 express doesn't include MFC and 2013 upgrade causes all kinds of complications.

Please if anyone has a nice solution for this - my strength is in C# but I'm willing to try any language that will work on Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg could/should work if you specify parameters for the video codec [the default is to highly compress, as you describe]. GL!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077 visit this link for working FFMPEG c++ mp4 format screen recorder application.

Answer (score 0):

I came across many solutions that could be of help to you,

- Camstudio
- [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)
- [OBS-open broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.net)
- [taksi](http://taksi.sourceforge.net/)
- icecream screen recorder
- openCV  with "highgui"

I am still searching a similar solution as you want, if you have a working solution, drop it here.