# Screen capture with libavcodec/ffmpeg, and write it to mp4 file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directshow, libavcodec

I'm trying to (programatically) record the screen with DirectShow screen driver. I wrote some quick and (very) dirty code to try to get that to work (http://pastebin.com/ZJuhZRCz) based on ffmpeg examples but I have lots of trouble figuring out what time_base/framerate to use. If i leave the time_base/framerate parts empty I only get a single still frame. If i change them to any values, the video just turns black.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the output file settings, but I just ran out of ideas on what to try. Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what dshow capture filter? does ffmpeg on command line work?

Comment: @rogerdpack https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free this capture filter (if i understand your question). Yes command line works fine.

Comment: unfortunately don't know too much about libav https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav* maybe ask on the libav-user mailing list?

Comment: following github link :https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp  directs to the answer of screen capture and store frames in MP4 file using FFMPEG - C++ (ubuntu ).  refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077