# How to convert JPEG to Flash video with PHP?

Tags: php, flash, video, jpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert series of jpegs to flv using imagemagik and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404427/how-to-convert-series-of-jpegs-to-flv-using-imagemagik-and-php)

Is it even possible to convert a batch of JPEG images into Flash video?

If so, any recommendations on how would I start on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SWFBitmap](http://php.net/manual/en/swfbitmap.construct.php) to import image to a Movie [Using PHP Ming](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php)  Function to [SWFMovie]

Examples

```
$img = new SWFBitmap(file_get_contents('test.jpg'));

$s = new SWFShape();
$imgf = $s->addFill($img);
$s->setRightFill($imgf);
$s->movePenTo(0, 0);
$s->drawLineTo($img->getWidth(), 0);
$s->drawLineTo($img->getWidth(), $img->getHeight());
$s->drawLineTo(0, $img->getHeight());
$s->drawLineTo(0, 0);

$m = new SWFMovie();
$m->setDimension($img->getWidth() * 2, $img->getHeight() * 2);
$is = $m->add($s);
$is->moveTo($img->getWidth() / 2, $img->getHeight() / 2);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    $is->skewx(0.02);
    $is->skewy(- 0.03);
    $m->nextframe();
}

$m->save('image.swf');
```

Image Slide Show

- [Create a swf slideshow](http://www.navioo.com/php/tutorials/Create_a_swf_slideshow_832.html)
- [jpg slideshow version 2.0](http://www.gazbming.com/getexample.php?id=3)