# FFMPEG produce sharper image from audio to video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am using ffmpeg to create video file from by using the loop_input command and create an flv file as a wrapper then export it as mp4. For some reason when the video plays the image is clear as time goes on it starts to get really pixelated. Is there something I need to do to retain the quality during the looping or anywhere else that would help?

This is my video out parameters, not the whole line.

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i myimage.jpg -r 20 -g 20 -vcodec flv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, thanks to this post I see what my problem was.

[Image sequence to video quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158235/image-sequence-to-video-quality)

I forgot to add a bit rate. I'm used to only setting bit rates when dealing with video only but sense I was converting it to a video, of course it still needs it or it will guess and it will be very low. I used -b 1000k and the image looks great.