# How can i create a video file with a bunch of image directories?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an NSMutableArray which there are image paths in it. I want to combine them into a video file. Is there any way to do that? I've searched it but i couldn't find any spesific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FFmpeg` library can convert image-sequences into videos.
Compile `FFmpeg` for iOS and run `FFmpeg` through `NSTask`.

Two related questions to get you started:

- [Image sequence to video quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158235/image-sequence-to-video-quality)
- [Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK for video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)