# Recording live stream from IP camera (MJPEG Compression)

Tags: php, video-streaming, video-capture, ip-camera

I have a live stream from a Tenvis IP camera through http live streaming and its in mjpeg compression.

I am trying to save it to a file, and I have tried using php to do this. my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$input = fopen("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81/videostream.cgi?user=user&pwd=admin&resolution=8");
$output = fopen("video.mpg", "c+");
$end = time() + 60;
do {
    fwrite($output, (fread($input, 30000)), 30000);
} while (time() <= $end);
fclose($output);
fclose($input);
echo "<h1>Recording</h1>";
?>
```

The code I have creates the file but doesn't write anything to it. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia page about MJPEG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP), the MJPEG stream over HTTP is basically a sequence of JPEG frames, accompanied by a special mime-type. In order to capture these and save them to a video file, I am not sure you can simply write the incoming data to an .mpg file and have a working video.

To be honest, I am not quite sure why your script does not write anything at all, but I came across the following page, which, although it is written for specific software, provides examples on how to capture an MJPEG stream and pass it on to a browser:
http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MjpegFrameGrabPHP

You could try one of their examples, and instead of passing it to the browser, save it to a file. You can see they read one image at a time:

```
while (substr_count($r,"Content-Length") != 2) $r.=fread($input,512);
$start = strpos($r,'ÿ');
$end   = strpos($r,$boundary,$start)-1;
$frame = substr("$r",$start,$end - $start);
```

If this does fix the stream capturing part but not saving it as a video, another option would be to save all frames individually as a JPEG file, then later stitch them together using a tool such as ffmpeg to create a video: [Image sequence to video quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158235/image-sequence-to-video-quality)

**Update**
If you decide to take the ffmpeg road, it is also possible to capture the stream using ffmpeg only. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/474004/mjpeg-recording-with-ffmpeg-preserving-time-information) question for an example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when a camera supports mjpeg, it also supports rtsp and as such you might want to pursue that as a solution for what you are trying to accomplish. With that, its fairly simple to record using an app like VLC.