# ffmpeg convertation image<->video causes artefacts

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, image-compression

I want to convert video to images, do some image processing and convert images back to video.

Here is my commands:

```
./ffmpeg -r 30 -i $VIDEO_NAME "image%d.png"

./ffmpeg -r 30 -y -i "image%d.png" output.mpg
```

But in `output.mpg` video I have some artefacts [like in jpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact).

Also I don't know how to detrmine fps, I set fps=30 (`-r 30`).
When I use above first command without `-r` it produces a lot of images > 1kk, but than I use `-r 30` option it produce same number of images as this command calculationg number of frames:

```
FRAME_COUNT=`./ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 $VIDEO_NAME`
```

So my questions are:

1. How to determine frame rate ?
2. How to convert images to video and don't reduce initial quality?

**UPDATE:**

Seems this helped, after I removed `-r` option
[Image sequence to video quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158235/image-sequence-to-video-quality)

so resulting command is :

```
./ffmpeg -y -i "image%d.png" -vcodec mpeg4 -b $BITRATE output_$BITRATE.avi
```

but I'm still not sure how to select bitrate.

How can I see bitrate of original `.mp4` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `qscale` parameter instead of bitrate e.g.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "image%d.png" -vcodec mpeg4 -q:v 1 output_1.avi
```

`q:v` is short for `qscale:v`. `1` may produce too large files. `4`-`6` is a decent range to use.

Comment: Can I see bitrate of original `.mp4` file?

Comment: By running ffprobe and parsing the output.